# How can I start an exe file with an input parameter?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have built a WPF application. The application has an input parameter. From Visual Studio I have configured that parameter from properties --> Debug. But now I want to generate a .exe file and that when the user double clicks on this file, then the application starts.

How I can do this?

I'm thinking of creating a batch file but I don't like this solution.

Comment: If you want parameters to be constant, why use parameters ?

Comment: If you know what the paramters are goinf to be, create a shortcut specifying the params.

Comment: You can create a wrapping application (a console app, for example) that is in the same folder with your app that works as a starter executable. Or you can popup a window with a textbox for input parameters on startup of your wpf application and ask the user (while putting default values in textbox for convenience).

Comment: or...in your program make the command line arguments optional. when you pass them in via visual studio, they get taken into account. if not found, default them to a particular value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of points:
Is the parameter usually the same? Might as well make it a default and initialise to that in the C# code so the user can just double click on the exe.

Otherwise a batch or shortcut link for each possible value is the only option and it is a bit nasty:

Go to command prompt

```
echo C:\...path\my.exe parameter > myapp.bat
```

Comment: the parameter are the same, I want that the user do double click on ONE file then the application start

Comment: so on right click, do you want them to select the right value for the parameter? Because if they are always the same, you might as well make it the default value in C# code and do nothing else.

Comment: sorry double click on one file. I don't want to set this value as default value because, I want 'now' create a simple file demo, double click on one file, the application start, but if I set this value as default value in the code, everty time that I want build a release I must change the code

Comment: @bircastri how about using an app.config file. That is what most of us do when we have information that we change without wanting to recompile.

Comment: Totally agree with Jeremy, this sounds like config to me.